# Как в качестве метки на карте использовать логотип компании?

Tags: яндекс-карты

подскажите, можно ли в качестве метки на карте использовать не стандартные решения, а логотип компании?
если да, то как это реализуется?

Answer (score 0):

API предоставляет возможность задавать меткам собственные изображения.

```
myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(myMap.getCenter(), {
        hintContent: 'Собственный значок метки',
        balloonContent: 'Это красивая метка'
    }, {
        // Опции.
        // Необходимо указать данный тип макета.
        iconLayout: 'default#image',
        // Своё изображение иконки метки.
        iconImageHref: 'images/myIcon.gif',
        // Размеры метки.
        iconImageSize: [30, 42],
        // Смещение левого верхнего угла иконки относительно
        // её "ножки" (точки привязки).
        iconImageOffset: [-5, -38]
    })
```

Ссылка на пример в песочнице https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1